# Extend and restriction of operator on $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let ‎$‎‎H$ ‎be a ‎Hilbert ‎space ,‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎‎B(H)$ ‎be  ‎bounded ‎operators ‎on ‎‎$‎‎H$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎K(H)$ ‎be ‎compact ‎operators ‎on ‎‎$‎‎H$‎.

Assume ‎that ‎‎$‎‎M$ ‎is a ‎close‎d subspace of ‎$‎‎H$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎u:M‎\longrightarrow M‎$ ‎is ‎bounded. ‎So I can say ‎$‎‎H=M‎\oplus ‎‎‎M^{‎\bot}$‎.

I define
‎
‎$‎‎‎\widehat{u}‎:H‎\longrightarrow H‎$ ‎such ‎that  ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎\widehat{u}= u $ ‎on ‎‎$‎‎M$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎\widehat{u}=0 $ ‎on ‎‎$‎‎M^‎{\bot‎}$‎‎.

‎
Q1:" If ‎$‎u \in B(M)‎$ ‎then ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎\widehat{u}‎\in B(H)‎‎$ ‎‎"‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎.Is it true?‎
‎

Q2:"If‎$‎u \in K(M)‎$then ‎‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎\widehat{u}‎\in K(H)‎‎$".Is it true?‎
‎

Q3:‎"If ‎$‎‎T\in K(H) $ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎T:M‎\longrightarrow ‎H‎$‎‎ ‎then ‎‎‎$‎‎T$ is compact‎‎‎‎".Is it true?
‎

Q4:"If ‎$‎‎T\in K(H) $ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎T(M)‎\subseteq M‎$ ‎then ‎‎$‎‎T\in K(M)$‎".Is it true?

Comment: Is there anything you tried to solve those questions except posting them here?

Comment: Yes.i want to solve some problems in postliminal c star algebras,so i need these statments.are all questions true?

Comment: $1$ and $2$ are true, $3$ is true as $T \in K(H)$, so $T$ compact, $4$ is not well defined as $T:H \to H$, so $T \not\in B(M)$, let alone in $K(M)$.

Comment: @Hetebrij Why do you say about 4 that $T$ is not in $B(H)$ which contains $K(H)$ as a subset?

Comment: @Urgje Because I say that $T \not \in B(M)$, as you should consider the restriction of $T$ to $M$ for that.

Comment: @Hetebrij I don't get it. Under 4 his first assumption is that $T$ is contained in $K(H)$. But $K(H)$ is a subset of $B(H)$. Do you say that this is not compatible with $T(M)$ being contained in $M$?

Comment: @Urgje, We have $T \in K(H) \subset B(H)$, thus $T : H \to H$. Furthermore, we have $T(M) \subset M$, so if we restrict $T$ to $M$, then $T|_{M}: M \to M$. Thus $T|_{M} \in B(H)$, but $T$ itself is a map from $H$ to $H$, not from $M$ to $M$.

Comment: @Hetebrij Yes, I think that 4 was formulated somewhat sloppily. Clearly the restriction of $T$ to $M$ is compact and this is what he might have meant.

Comment: ‎$‎‎T\in K(H) $ so by 3 we can say ‎$‎‎T|_{M}:M‎\longrightarrow H‎$ ‎is ‎compact‎.thus ‎‎‎‎$‎‎T|_{M}:M‎\longrightarrow T(M)‎$ ‎is compact and because ‎$‎‎M$is ‎closed ‎sub‎space ‎of ‎‎$‎‎H$ ‎‎‎and ‎‎$‎‎T(M)‎\subseteq M‎$ ‎so ‎‎$‎‎T:M‎‎\longrightarrow ‎‎M$ ‎is ‎compact.Am I‎ ‎right?‎